# How I can Select a Table from a SQL Server Database correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, datatable

I want to built a connection to a SQL Server database with a `SELECT` command.

The connection is ok but I get a error if I make a error. I want to get the `Select` values to a `DataTable`.

This I get if I try this:

> The SELECT-Perssision was denied for UserApplicationRequests-Objekt, DB_CM0-Datenbank, dbo-Schema.

I use a Login Dialog in my application for building the connection string. In this form:

```
user id=[username];password=[password];server=[servername];Trusted_Connection=yes;database=DB_CM0
```

And here is my code for the `SELECT` command.

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql) 
{
            using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                    DataTable tb = new DataTable();

                    adapter.Fill(tb);

                    con.Open();

                    command.ExecuteReader();

                    return tb;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
   }
}
```

My SQL command:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [DB_CM0].[dbo].[UserApplicationRequests]";
```

Comment: It may be the user do not have permissions to do select operation on tables.Grant permission to the user and check.

Comment: The Problem is if the user make it on the sql server than it works.

Comment: Not your answer, but, do not write empty try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

its happening because of security issue..below steps might help you

1. Open SQL Server Management studio
2. Navigate to the database 'CNET_85731' >> Security >> Users
3. Right click on the one which you are using in your code
4. And finally, just uncheck 'db_denydatareader' inside "Database Role
   membership" section.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string uses the sql authentication login method and integrated security login method simultaneously... Windows integrated security will have the priority in this case and attempt to use your windows user permissions to interact with the database... maybe this is not the behaviour you intended.

Comment: Remove one of the authentication methods from the connection string.